# Wait for function to finish before you can do it again

Tags: javascript, html

I have an onclick event on my image that calls a function. Now I don't want the function to be called again while it's still going. How can I do this?

HTML:

```html
<img
  class="rocket2"
  id="rocket2"
  ondblclick="myMove()"
  src="img/footerIcon.png"
/>

<div class="rocketEE" id="rocketEE">
  <span>
    <i class="fin-top"></i>
    <i class="fin-bottom"></i>
    <i class="faya"></i>
    <i class="wastes"><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```js
<script>
  function myMove() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("rocketEE");
    var pos = -1100;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 1);
    function frame() {
      if (pos == 600) {
        clearInterval(id);
      } else {
        pos++;
        elem.style.left = pos + "px";
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: whats the probelm? error? does it still run een after it should be done?

Comment: @Ifaruki The problem was that you can call it while it's still going. But it's solved now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A global variable is one way, but you should not get into the habit of using global variables for things like this. Much better is to store that variable in the scope of what is using it. The element itself is a good a place as any:

```
function myMove() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("rocketEE");   
    if(elem.isAnimating)
        return;

    var pos = -1100;
    elem.isAnimating = true;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 1);
    function frame() {
        if (pos == 600) {
            clearInterval(id);
            elem.isAnimating = true;
        } else {
            pos++; 
            elem.style.left = pos + 'px'; 
        }
    }
}
```

Just a sidenote: This isn't a great way to do animation, for one thing a 1 millisecond rate is going to be far too fast, and there are much better ways - for example [css and Animation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Using_the_Web_Animations_API)